# Application Settings Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

i'm new to azure and i have the following issue:

i have this key in my web.config: 

*add key="BlobStorageConnectionString" value="xxxxxxxx"*

The thing is when i add it to app settings in azure app service, when i search in the logs i get this:

 *Getting "BlobStorageConnectionString" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL

 Getting "BlobStorageConnectionString" from ConfigurationManager: PASS.*

 i've already tried a few tutorials, but i still can't find a reason.

 I'm running out of ideas, any suggestions?

Comment: Provide code how you are reading those settings. Also what do you use c#, node js?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat, i'm using C#, the line of code is:     
     var d = 
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BlobStorageConnectionString")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655648/cloudconfigurationmanager-vs-webconfigurationmanager

Comment: Is it Full framework or .net core? Please provide more information about your application and update your question its hard to help with information you did provide.

Comment: It’s net fwk 4.7.2

Comment: Have you tried to use ConfigurationManager ?

Answer (score 2):

If you add the Storage Account string in the Application Settings, it will be stored as an environment.So you could read it with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("storageconnectionstring")`.
Then parse it the code will be like below shows.

```
        string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("storageconnectionstring");

        // Check whether the connection string can be parsed.
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the CloudBlobClient that represents the Blob storage endpoint for the storage account.
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
              ........
              ........
           }
       }
```

And you could also configure your connection in your app like WebJob, you could use `JobHostConfiguration()`. And the code would be like this.And the connection name should be **AzureWebJobsStorage**.

```
   var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.DashboardConnectionString = "";
```

Also you could choose to use Configuration Classes,about the details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#working-with-the-configuration-classes).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.